# How to map a nested array in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

Ok. I am super lost here. I am attempting to return an a value from a nested array of objects. Here is what the database looks like.

[image: picture of database]

Each object returns an array of staff as seen in this console log. [image: picture of console.log]

I cannot for the life of me display both names out of the array. I used the `.flatMap()` function to extract the data from the array, but when I go to render it in the component only the first name shows. Here is my codebase. Right now I am just console logging the data using `.flatMap()`

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import Button from '../components/Button';
import ActivitySummary from '../components/ActivitySummary';

import { projectsInfoDetails } from '../actions/projectInfoActions';
import { projectContacts } from '../actions/projectContactActions';
import { projectStaff } from '../actions/accountableStaffActions';

import SectionHeader from '../components/SectionHeader';
import Loader from '../components/Loader';
import Message from '../components/Message';

const ProjectScreen = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const projectInfoDetails = useSelector(state => state.projectInfoDetails);
  const { loading, error, projects } = projectInfoDetails;

  const contactDetails = useSelector(state => state.projectContactDetails);
  const { projectContact } = contactDetails;

  const projectAccountableStaff = useSelector(state => state.projectStaff);
  const { accountableProjectStaff } = projectAccountableStaff;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(projectsInfoDetails(match.params.id));
    dispatch(projectContacts(match.params.id));
    dispatch(projectStaff(match.params.id));
  }, [dispatch, match]);

  const lastName = projectContact.map(l => l.contact.lastName);
  const firstName = projectContact.map(f => f.contact.firstName);

  const accountableStaffLastNames = accountableProjectStaff.flatMap(
    ({ accountableStaff }) => accountableStaff.map(data => data.lastName)
  );

  console.log(accountableStaffLastNames);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <SectionHeader sectionName='Project' />
        <Button buttonName='Edit Project' />
      </div>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : error ? (
        <Message variant='danger'>{error}</Message>
      ) : (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: '#F8F8F8' }}>
          <Table className='borderless'>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <strong>Name: </strong>
                  {projects.name}
                </td>
                <td>
                  <strong>Status: </strong>
                  {projects.status}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <strong>State: </strong>
                  {projects.state}
                </td>
                <td>
                  <strong>County: </strong>
                  {projects.county}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <strong>Congressional District: </strong>
                  {projects.district}
                </td>
                <td>
                  <strong>Type: </strong>
                  {projects.type}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <strong>Funding Source: </strong>
                  <br />
                  {`${projects.fundingSource} ${projects.fundingSourceName}`}
                </td>
                <td>
                  <strong>Funding Source Goal: </strong>
                  <br />
                  {projects.fundingSourceGoal}
                </td>
                <td>
                  <strong>Start Date: </strong>
                  <br />
                  <Moment format='MM/DD/YYYY'>{projects.startDate}</Moment>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <strong>End Date: </strong>
                  <br />
                  {projects.endDate === null ? (
                    ''
                  ) : (
                    <Moment format='MM/DD/YYYY'>{projects.endDate}</Moment>
                  )}
                </td>
                <td>
                  <strong>Funding Percent: </strong>
                  <br />
                  {projects.fundingPercent}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <strong>Contact: </strong>
                  {firstName} {lastName}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <strong>Start Date: </strong>
                  <Moment format='MM/DD/YYYY'>
                    {projects.projectStartDate}
                  </Moment>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <strong>End Date: </strong>
                  {projects.projectEndDate === null ? (
                    ''
                  ) : (
                    <Moment format='MM/DD/YYYY'>
                      {projects.projectEndDate}
                    </Moment>
                  )}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colSpan='5'>
                  <strong>Goals and Objectives: </strong>
                  {projects.goalsAndObjectives}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colSpan='5'>
                  <strong>Success Description: </strong>
                  {projects.successDescription}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <strong>Accountable Staff: </strong>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <strong>Project ID: </strong>
                  {projects.projectId}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </div>
      )}

      <ActivitySummary />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ProjectScreen;
```

Comment: Can you post your `response` json also. It would be better if you add your code [here](https://react.new/) which is easy to debug others

Comment: your `flatMap` is just grabbing the `data.lastName`. Do you need `data.firstName` as well? If so, just return it in an array or object like `accountableStaff.map(data => [data.firstName, data.lastName])` or a string `accountableStaff.map(data => data.firstName + ' ' + data.lastName)`

Comment: I don't see a "first" or "last" name property in ***any*** of the screen shots shared. I ***do*** however see a `name` property. Please post *actual* formatted code/response/data snippets, images are not searchable and in this case, not helpful either. The data you are processing looks to be already stored in your redux store, may we see your reducers?